# Extract string starting from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a URL:

```
/c/s/www.local.com/pure/123/india/news/hunt-still-on-for-biker-who-gunned-down-man
```

I want to extract the string starting from /pure:

```
/pure/123/india/news/hunt-still-on-for-biker-who-gunned-down-man
```

What is the best way to do it in python.

Comment: `s[s.index("/pure"):]`

Answer (score 2):

Use `index()` and the `[]` notation.

```
str = "/c/s/www.local.com/pure/123/india/news/hunt-still-on-for-biker-who-gunned-down-man"
print(str[str.index("/pure"):])
```

`str[index:]` means grab all chars from `str` starting at `index` till the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
url[url.index('/pure'):]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of characters is always the same from the beginning of the string you can just dismiss the first characters.
ex. `a_string = "/c/s/www.local.com/pure/123/india/news/hunt-still-on-for-biker-who-gunned-down-man"`

`print (a_string[24:])`

Then you can consider regular expressions, as well as other methods.